# Calling the event function and using the .bind to make my canvas rectangles appear grey after the cursor has rolled over it - Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I need the rectangles to appear grey after the cursor has been rolled over it. But I am not sure how exactly to do that. I know it has to do with the "Enter" function and maybe changing the colour to grey.

If anyone can help me with the code bit that would be great. Also I assume that if I want to repeat this process for a new level would I use a loop counter? Thanks.  Here is my code for the Canvas:

```
canvas = Canvas(PageOne, width=600, height=800)
canvas.pack()

#                                  x1  y1  x2  y2
greenBox = canvas.create_rectangle(40, 60, 90, 110, fill="green")
RedBox = canvas.create_rectangle(110, 60, 160, 110, fill="red")
BlueBox = canvas.create_rectangle(180, 60, 230, 110, fill="blue", activefill="grey")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example, when your mouse cursor hovers over a rectangle for the first time, its color turns to grey:

```
import tkinter as tk

def turngrey(e):
    canvas.itemconfig('current', fill='grey')

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=800)
canvas.pack()

greenBox = canvas.create_rectangle(40, 60, 90, 110, fill="green", tags=('turntogrey'))
RedBox = canvas.create_rectangle(110, 60, 160, 110, fill="red", tags=('turntogrey'))
BlueBox = canvas.create_rectangle(180, 60, 230, 110, fill="blue", tags=('turntogrey'))

canvas.tag_bind('turntogrey', '<Enter>', turngrey)

root.mainloop()
```