# Creating the flash in my canvas rectangles

Tags: python, tkinter

Thank you novel about the note, i need to know if im doing this right and what to do next because i get this message currently:

```
line 52, in flashbox
    canvas_instance.itemconfigure(tag, state='hidden' )
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'itemconfigure'
```

Also for some reason i can't use the '' function because it says its illegal?

```
#                                  x1  y1  x2  y2
greenBox = canvas.create_rectangle(40, 60, 90, 110,   fill="green", tags= 
('hiddentonormal'))
RedBox = canvas.create_rectangle(110, 60, 160, 110,   fill="red", tags= 
('hiddentonormal'))
BlueBox = canvas.create_rectangle(180, 60, 230, 110,  fill="blue", tags= 
('hiddentonormal'))

canvas.tag_bind('turntogrey', '<Enter>', turngrey)

def canvas_instance(e):
    canvas_instance.itemconfigure(tag, state='normal')

def flashbox(e):
    canvas_instance.itemconfigure(tag, state='hidden')


canvas.tag_bind('hiddentonormal', '<Enter>', canvas_instance)


canvas.tag_bind('hiddentonormal', '<Enter>', flashbox)
```

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. Show us a [mcve] of a problem you have and we'll go from there. Start with looking into `Canvas.itemconfig()`.

Comment: i know, its more the fact that ive been trying to find out the variables for making it flash but ive looked all over the internet and cannot find it at all :( sorry

Comment: You mean a function? There is no built in flash function, you'll have to make your own. Use `canvas_instance.itemconfigure(tag, state='hidden')` and `state='normal'` to make the flashing effect.

Comment: Did i do it right? Novel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slight modification of my answer from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692356/calling-the-event-function-and-using-the-bind-to-make-my-canvas-rectangles-appe) that makes the boxes flash a few times before turning grey:

```
import tkinter as tk   # avoid star imports


def turngrey(e):
    flash(5)

def flash(n):
    color = ['yellow', 'black'][n%2]
    canvas.itemconfig('current', fill=color)
    if n >= 0:
        root.after(100, flash, n-1)             # <-- no loops: use root.after to repeat a GUI action
    else:
        canvas.itemconfig('current', fill='grey')


root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=800)
canvas.pack()

greenBox = canvas.create_rectangle(40, 60, 90, 110, fill="green", tags=('turntogrey'))
RedBox = canvas.create_rectangle(110, 60, 160, 110, fill="red", tags=('turntogrey'))
BlueBox = canvas.create_rectangle(180, 60, 230, 110, fill="blue", tags=('turntogrey'))

canvas.tag_bind('turntogrey', '<Enter>', turngrey)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate :)